# Get a key in a JavaScript object by its value and rename it

Tags: javascript

I have a list of variables that I will form into an array with keys and values. However, before making them as array I want to check if any of their values matches a
specific string and change their keys names into something else.

Lets say this is the list of variables

```
customer1 = "Jack", customerDate1 = "08/13/2021", customer2 = "Michael", customerDate2 = "01/01/2021", customer3 = "Luna",customerDate3 = "03/10/2021";
```

The array before running condition check will be

```
data = [{key1:"Jack", keyDate1:"08/13/2021",key2:"Michael", keyDate2:"01/01/2021",key3:"Luna", keyDate3:"10" }];
```

Lets say the condition is:

> customerName = "Jack";

I want the cross check customerName variable with the following variables (customer1,customer2,customer3) and if the condition meets any of them, then their keys in the array changes:

for example the condition meets customer1 then both keys of customer1 and customerDate1 changes to something else, to become something like

```
data = [{conditionMet1:"Jack", conditionDateMet1:"08/13/2021",key2:"Michael", keyDate2:"01/01/2021",key3:"Luna", keyDate3:"10" }];
```

I am appreciating any help or guidance.

Comment: suggest you to share sample data/input and expected output, it will be easier for us to understand your question, also have you tried any solution at all?

Comment: the data is an array with just one object ?

Comment: why you want to do this !!!!?

Comment: @Isaac I added some data to the code. Yes I did try via looping through conditions but I want it in a form of function otherwise the code will be so long

Comment: @nAviD I am trying to store that data in a server but before that, the keys names have to change to serve pulling data from server later on

Comment: When you have numbers in your variable/key names, that suggesst to me that maybe an array of objects with the _same_ property names would be more useful. e.g.:  `customers = [{ name: "Jack", date: "08/13/2021" }, { name: "Michael", date: "01/01/2021" }, { name: "Luna", date: "03/10/2021" }]`

Comment: @Wyck The issue is that this data will be pushed to be saved at a database at same place, pushing it that way will always override the last value and end up saving one name and one date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit tricky as alghoritm but it works:

```js
let data = [{key1:"Jhon", keyDate1:"08/13/2021",key2:"Eric", keyDate2:"01/01/2021",key3:"Jack", keyDate3:"10" }];

let i = 1;
let result = [];
let explored = [];
data.forEach(x => {
   let resultObj = {};
   for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(x)) {
      let newKey = key;
      let newKeyDate = null;
      if (val === "Jack") {
          newKey = "conditionMet" + i;
          newKeyDate = "conditionDateMet" + i;
      }
      if (!explored.includes(key)) resultObj[newKey] = val;
      if (newKeyDate) {
         resultObj[newKeyDate] = x["keyDate" + i];
         explored.push("keyDate" + i)
      }
      if(!key.includes("Date")) i++;
   }
   result.push(resultObj)
})
console.log(result)
```

Basically for each element in `data` I explore all the `entries` and if I found condition I add `conditionMet1` and `conditionDateMet1` to object, otherwise what I found on object itself.

Comment: Im sorry, can you check the code again? If I check position of the condition to be met, like moving "Jack" to key2 or key3, it gives wrong result?

Comment: @ZeroByZero I'm checking

Comment: @ZeroByZero done! `i` value must be incremented only if `!key.includes("Date")`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not very elegant, but for the example given you could do something like this:

```
if(specialCondition){
  data = [{specialKey1:customer1, specialDate1:customerDate1,key2:customer2...];
}else{
  data = [{key1:customer1, keyDate1:customerDate1,key2:customer2...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to rename a key but you can always create a new key by

```
object["newKeyName"] = object.previousKey
```

And optionally you can remove the old key by

```
delete object.previousKey
```

That way you will remove the previous key if you don't want it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 6 variables.

```
customer1, customerDate1, customer2, customerDate2, customer3,customerDate3;
```

You could make an array, *by customer*

```
const data = [{
  id: customer1,
  date: customerDate1
},{
  id: customer2,
  date: customerDate2
},{
  id: customer3,
  date: customerDate3
}];
```

This is now quite useful.  Say you want to know which customer meets *some condition*. (for example `id` is "Jack"), using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const jack = data.find(item => item.id === "Jack");
console.log(jack);
```

Or to find which customers have a date before "now", using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const now = Date.now();
const beforeNow = data.filter(item => item.date < now);
console.log(beforeNow);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I am sorry, I forgot to mention that this data will be pushed to be saved at a database in the server at the same place. Like customer profile. Having the keys all with same names, will always override last values and end up storing one id, one date while I am trying to save all 3

Comment: @ZeroByZero that requirement needs a lot more explanation in the original question.  This is unlike any database I've ever heard of, to do what you describe (overriding last values).  Can the "values" not just be an array?  or an object containing the array?  like `{dont_mess_with_my_data: [{
  id: customer1,
  date: customerDate1
},{
  id: customer2,
  date: customerDate2
},{
  id: customer3,
  date: customerDate3
}]}`